# Public key stored in server is different from what is shown in OpenSSL

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, letsencrypt

I obtained an SSL certificate from LetsEncrypt for my web application using Apache web server. LetsEncrypt generated these 4 files:

```
cert.pem  chain.pem  fullchain.pem  privkey.pem
```

As I understand, `cert.pem` is the public key. Now I tried to verify that this public key is indeed being served by

```
 openssl s_client -connect my.domain.com:443 | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout
```

But the output is completely different from the contents which I see in my `cert.pem`.

Additionally, I also tried Exporting the certificate in Base64 format from Google Chrome for the same domain. Again very different from `cert.pem`.

So my question is why is the exported certificate(via Chrome) and public key(via OpenSSL) different from my `cert.pem`? Are all of them different formats of the same key? If yes, how do I obtain one from other using OpenSSL?

Comment: What are you seeing as the `subject` in the certificate retrieved by the `openssl s_client` command?  Is it a FQDN for a different site hosted on the same server as your site?  If so, then the problem may be due to the fact that the server is hosting multiple `https` sites (by way of `SNI`), and the certificate that the `openssl s_client` command is retrieving is that of the default site.  If that's the case, then you'll have to use the `-servername` option with `openssl s_client` to make it use `SNI` to get the certificate for your site.

Comment: `cert.pem` is the (server/leaf) _certificate_, not the publickey. A cert _contains_ a publickey, but is not the same as the publickey, and does not look the same. However a cert exported from Chrome _is_ a cert and should match. Try _looking at the information in_ each of the different certs. Is the cert seen by `s_client` the same as seen by Chrome? How about other browsers? How about other systems or devices (like a phone instead of a computer)? Where is the server (in your home, an office, or a cloud)?

Comment: Thanks @mti2935  and dave_thompson_085 I checked again. The exported certificate matches cert.pem. I might have made a mistake yesterday.